# What does "partition access restriction" entail?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, security, ata

The database entries on the [SMARTHDD](https://smarthdd.com/) website ([example](https://smarthdd.com/database/APPLE-HDD-ST3000DM001/AQ03/)) have an entry called "partition access restriction". What is this feature and what does it do? I searched the internet for a feature that might sound like this in the ATA command set, but I cannot find anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is speculation but this drive appears to support some features I had never heard of:

> Mobile HDD Self-Encrypting Drive models have the following additional
> features • **16 independent data bands**

For each of these bands a unique data encryption key can be assigned. AIUI these data bands can be created by specifying start LBA and number of LBA sectors. Now if you create partitions that match these bands you could restrict access to such a partition using the built-in encryption feature.

Quotes from the PDF:

"When shipped from the factory, the drive is configured with a single data band called Band 0 (also known as the Global Data Band) which comprises LBA 0 through LBA max. The host may allocate additional bands (Band1 to Band15) by specifying a start LBA and an LBA range."

And ..

"A unique data encryption key is used for each of the drive's possible 16 data bands"

And ..

"Each data band has its own drive-generated encryption key. The host may change the Encryption Key or the password when required"

Source: https://www.seagate.com/www-content/product-content/seagate-laptop-fam/mobile-hdd/en-us/docs/100775165b.pdf

Comment: Is it the same for other drives that support "partition access restriction"?

Comment: I suppose so, you'd have to try finding documentation for such drives. As I said it seems a plausible explanation to me, you can ask the smarthdd guy.